# Can't Debug javascript on IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging

I'm trying to debug javascript code on ie11 but when opening debugger tab on developer tools I can't see any code as you see in the below image
[image: debugger not displaying any code]

It was working properly before. I reset setting , removed history, reinstalled IE , stopped firewall , but still the same . I'm using windows 10, and edge debugging tools works properly

if any one faced problem like this before appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you dragged the vertical separator between the left pane (with the source code) and the right pane completely to the left, so only the right pane remains visible now.

Move your mouse to the left margin of the debugger window and drag the separator back to the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same issue on IE 11. Just move your mouse to the right, as in the image below:

[image]